# Sending a string to arduino and is not reacting to it

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string

I am trying to move servos with a VR headset, I am using the Unreak 4 Arduino Plugin, but that is not the problem. I send the rotation Y and Z from the headset, convert them to int and then send them together as an int separated by commas. Here's what it does: It gets the rotation Z, it converts it to int, then it converts it to String, I add a comma at the end of the String, then I add the rotation Y after the comma, and it returns me: "rotationZ","rotationY" (the values between " are the numbers sent by Unreal to arduino), these results may come in negative or positive value.

Then inside arduino I have this code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;  // Crea un Objeto servo

int angle = 10;
int posicion = 10;    // Variable de la posicion del servo

String user_input1;

int r;
int g;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo1.attach(2);  // Selecionamos el pin 2 como el pin de control para el servo
  servo2.attach(3);  // Selecionamos el pin 2 como el pin de control para el servo 

  servo1.write(0);
  servo2.write(0); 

  Serial.setTimeout(5);
}


void loop()
{    
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
  String firstValue  = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
 // String first = Serial.readString(); //next character is comma, so skip it using this
  String secondValue = Serial.readStringUntil(',');
//  String second =  Serial.readString();

   r = firstValue.toInt();
   g = secondValue.toInt();
    }
  if (r < 0)
  {
    r = r * -1;
  }

  if (g < 0)
  {
    g = g * -1;
  }


  Serial.println(r);
  Serial.println(g);

  servo1.write(r);
  servo2.write(g);

}
```

As you can see, it gets the numbers between the commas and then it converts them to int, and then it applies to the servos which are in pins number 2 and 3 (yes, everything is plugged in correctly), which it should then move them acordingly the position of the VR headset, I've also tried to make them always receive positive results but still doesn't work. I have searched over the internet on how to separate a string divided by commas and I still don't know if it's correctly done.

EDIT: I also tried to input the numbers in the console manually, and it gets them right and moves the servos but it still doesn't work with the VR. I also added Serial.setTimeout(5) to try if it works that way.

Thanks in advance for reading this bunch'o text about my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried to input the numbers in the console manually, and it gets them right and moves the servos but it still doesn't work with the VR.

This implies that the problem is in the code sending the data.  Get a terminal emulator program and hook that up to the code generating the data from the VR headset (you will need 'local echo' turned on).  I suspect you will see the headset is not writing the data in the format you expect.  Also it will let you capture a real sample of data that you can feed into you program to generate a repeatable test.

If this isn't the fault, then please can you post the a few lines of data so we can see whats wrong.

Comment: I have to apologize but, what do you mean by "terminal emulator program"? I am kinda new to this kind of programming with arduino.

Comment: I should apologise 20+ years of embedded development and I forget things like speaking English :)  What you need is a program that you run on your "PC" and it lets you talk to the serial port.  The serial monitor is a sort of basic terminal emulator, but I don't think it would work in this case.  So for Windows try "Terraterm" [https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en] or "Putty" [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html].  (Linux and Mac will need advice from someone else, sorry)